# Why changes the '&' character the output for these two codes?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, dereference

**First code:**

```
int a = 1;

void func(int* ptr) {
    ptr = &a;
}

int main() {
    int nvar = 2;
    int* pvar = &nvar;
    func(pvar);
    std::cout << *pvar;
}
//Output: 2
```

**Second code:**

```
int a = 1;

void func(int*& ptr) {
    ptr = &a;
}

int main() {
    int nvar = 2;
    int* pvar = &nvar;
    func(pvar);
    std::cout << *pvar;
}
//Output: 1
```

The only difference is the '&' character in the 'func' function. But can someone explain me, what it does in this situation?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: What do you think the `&` operator does? I suppose you have a purpose with it?

Comment: I know what it does, but in the second code it is combined with * , and I dont know what this combination means

Comment: In the first, `ptr` is passed by value, so the effect of assignment to it is not visible to the caller after the function returns.   In the second, `ptr` is passed by reference (due to the `&`) so the effect of assignment IS visible to the caller after the function returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know what it does, but in the second code it is combined with * , and I dont know what this combination means

`T&` denotes "reference to `T`".

Now replace `T` with whatever you like. Eg for pointer to `int`, `T==int*` we have `int*&` which is a reference to a pointer to `int`.

It is no different to passing non-pointers to functions as references. When `ptr` is passed by value then `func` works on a copy, when passed by reference `func` works on the instance passed in.

Comment: @klutt please dont do that. I want votes for the answer not for my name

Comment: It was not very serious. It was for your answer only. It was only a way to saty that I like your name.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` signifies [passing by reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr233.htm):

> The difference between pass-by-reference and pass-by-value is that modifications made to arguments passed in by reference in the called function have effect in the calling function, whereas modifications made to arguments passed in by value in the called function can not affect the calling function. Use pass-by-reference if you want to modify the argument value in the calling function. Otherwise, use pass-by-value to pass arguments.

I think that says it better than I could.